# Query to change the values of the column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this which contains a column number Order

```
FunctionID Name         ParentFunctionID OrderNo Enabled ControllerName ActionName
1          Nikhil       0                10      1       nik
2          Sahil        0                20      1       sah
3          With         2                10      1       sah            Withsnew
4          User         2                20      1       sah            users
5          Pen          2                10      0       sah            pend
44         User Summary 2                210     1       sah            usersummary
45         Summary      2                230     1       sah            summary
46         Hourly       1                231     1       nik            hourly
47         Code         1                232     1       nik            code
```

I want the Table like

```
FunctionID Name         ParentFunctionID OrderNo Enabled ControllerName ActionName
1          Nikhil       0                1       1       nik
2          Sahil        0                2       1       sah
3          With         2                1       1       sah            Withsnew
4          User         2                2       1       sah            users
5          Pen          2                3       0       sah            pend
44         User Summary 2                4       1       sah            usersummary
45         Summary      2                5       1       sah            summary
46         Hourly       1                1       1       nik            hourly
47         Code         1                2       1       nik            code
```

Comment: It looks as though you want to change the order numbers, but I can't see the pattern. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I understand the pattern. He wants the row numbers 1,2,3,4 to be displayed in the orderNo field.

Answer (score 0):

USE THE **ROWNUM** FEATURE:

```
SELECT 
  FunctionID ,
  Name ,
  ParentFunctionID, 
  ROWNUM AS ORDER_NO,
  Enabled,
  ControllerName ,
  ActionName 
FROM TABLE NAME;
```

If you want rownumbers to reset based on particular conditions, use **PARTITION** along with **ROW_NUMBER** AS:

```
SELECT 
  FunctionID ,
  Name ,
  ParentFunctionID, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentFunctionID ORDER BY FunctionID )  AS ORDER_NO,
  Enabled,
  ControllerName ,
  ActionName 
FROM TABLE NAME;
```

Comment: as per my knowledge ROWNUM is only supported in ORACLE, while the ques is related to SQL-SERVER, so here ROWNUM will not work.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai:  I have not used SQL Server and have experience with ORACLE only. Thank you for letting me know :-) . Btw, I guess my second query would be suitable for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to enumerate your rows partitioned by `ParentFunctionID` ordered by `FunctionID` to get the result you want.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c8fa6/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  FunctionID int,
  Name varchar(20),
  ParentFunctionID int,
  OrderNo int,
  Enabled bit,
  ControllerName varchar(20),
  ActionName varchar(20)
)

go

insert into YourTable values
(1 ,         'Nikhil      ', 0,                10 ,     1,       'nik',            '           '), 
(2 ,         'Sahil       ', 0,                20 ,     1,       'sah',            '           '),
(3 ,         'With        ', 2,                10 ,     1,       'sah',            'Withsnew   '),
(4 ,         'User        ', 2,                20 ,     1,       'sah',            'users      '),
(5 ,         'Pen         ', 2,                10 ,     0,       'sah',            'pend       '),
(44,         'User Summary', 2,                210,     1,       'sah',            'usersummary'),
(45,         'Summary     ', 2,                230,     1,       'sah',            'summary    '),
(46,         'Hourly      ', 1,                231,     1,       'nik',            'hourly     '),
(47,         'Code        ', 1,                232,     1,       'nik',            'code       ')
```

**Query 1**:

```
with C as
(
  select OrderNo,
         row_number() over(partition by ParentFunctionID order by FunctionID) as rn
  from YourTable
)
update C
set OrderNo = rn

select *
from YourTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c8fa6/1/0)**:

```
| FUNCTIONID |         NAME | PARENTFUNCTIONID | ORDERNO | ENABLED | CONTROLLERNAME |  ACTIONNAME |
|------------|--------------|------------------|---------|---------|----------------|-------------|
|          1 | Nikhil       |                0 |       1 |       1 |            nik |             |
|          2 | Sahil        |                0 |       2 |       1 |            sah |             |
|          3 | With         |                2 |       1 |       1 |            sah | Withsnew    |
|          4 | User         |                2 |       2 |       1 |            sah | users       |
|          5 | Pen          |                2 |       3 |       0 |            sah | pend        |
|         44 | User Summary |                2 |       4 |       1 |            sah | usersummary |
|         45 | Summary      |                2 |       5 |       1 |            sah | summary     |
|         46 | Hourly       |                1 |       1 |       1 |            nik | hourly      |
|         47 | Code         |                1 |       2 |       1 |            nik | code        |
```

Comment: A person with 75k repotation doesn't know, that giving just a piece of code, without even a tiny explanation is a very bad attitude here? I'm not surprised your answer was flagged as low-quality and to be deleted!

Comment: @trejder Working on it. It was not only low quality, It was also wrong.

Comment: @trejder Now I'm done until someone specifically ask about updateable CTE's.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ROW_NUMBER and partition by ParentFunctionID just like this

```
SELECT FunctionID, Name, ParentFunctionID
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentFunctionID ORDER BY FunctionID) OrderNo
, [Enabled], ControllerName, ActionName
FROM TABLENAME
```

this will return the resultset if you want to update you can modify the script.

I hope this is helpful.